# Meaning of one block into?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of ''one block into'' in the below sentences? Which grammar rule ?

**You own a house one block into the ward.**

Answer (score 2):

In the context of housing, a ***block*** is either a single (multi-storey) building containing multiple apartments / offices / etc., or a (usually rectangular) area between two pairs of intersecting roads, mostly or completely filled with buildings (houses / offices / shops / etc.).

And a ***ward*** usually refers to a residential area that's significant in the context of elections (all the voters who live in one ward get to decide who they will elect as their local councilor, for example).

I don't know the exact context of OP's example, but basically it means the addressee's house isn't on the very *edge* of a ward - there's one more block between his house and the one that's right on the electoral boundary (but considered to be *within* the ward).

---

Syntactically, it's the same general construction as...

> *I'm three weeks into my new job*

...meaning *I started my new job three weeks ago.*

Comment: Thank you. So, one block into the ward = pattern ?

Comment: If you mean the same "pattern" as *The bullet penetrated 2 inches into the tree-trunk* or *We were just 20 minutes into the movie when the alarm went off*, then yes. The idea being that the "amount" (of distance, time, or similar) is specified relative to the "outer edge" ("start of", for a time-based usages) of whatever the subject is now "inside" (literally, or metaphorically).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means *on the fringe of a district.*  The word *ward* means *an administrative division of a city*. I believe it means that the person doesn't live in the center of the ward but somewhere at the margins.

Comment: Little typo: it's fringe, not frindge

Comment: @Katy oops! thx